# Web Service Call - Auto Generated attributes

Tags: asmx

I'm trying to call a Soap Web Service, and I need to pass an Address Object to the Server. I can pass an existing address.Id to update an existing address, or if I leave the address.Id empty, it should be saved as a new Address. The Problem is that the Id is of long type, and it allways has a value of 0.

And this makes problems for the server, because even if the Id=0, the Server Side function will take the Address as Existing one, and it will start to search on the Database for an Address with Id=0. Of course there is no such address, and it throws an error.  When I try to call the Web Service with WebService Studio or SoapUI, and I delete the id manually, then It works as expected, as soon as I put  then it returns me an error - Address with Id=0 not found.

So the question is, how to change the webservice definitions, or the proxy classes so that it does not generates this id="0" at all?

Any Help would be great.

P.S. I cannot change the Server Side method, it would have been the easiest solution, but unfortunatelly is not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default .NET serializers, you may try with using the [XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx) attribute

If you are using other serializers there are normally attributes to control how the serialization occurs.